# passing variable to a thread after it already started

Tags: c++, boost, boost-thread

i am newbie in C++ and boost.

As part of my master thesis, i wrote a program which simulate a statistical model. During the computation, i use boost::thread to process my "center of mass vector", for saving some computation time. So far so good.

Now, i would like to take each result from the boost::thread (each time one element) and pass it to a running thread, which is going to preform recursive regression.

My questions:

- how can i pass my new computed element to the existing thread?
- how could i "wake-up" the thread, when i pass the new element?

i would be happy if someone could point me to an existing example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest possible way is to use [std::queue](http://www.sgi.com/tech/stl/queue.html), [boost::mutex](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.mutex_types.mutex) and [boost::conditional_variable](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_45_0/doc/html/thread/synchronization.html#thread.synchronization.condvar_ref.condition_variable). wrap any access to queue by mutex, after pushing to queue call `conditional_variable.notify_one()`. in consumer thread wait on conditional_variable until any result is ready, then process it.

Answer (score 0):

A proven way to control a thread from another thread is to send messages via a combination of a queue with a conditional variable.  Unfortunately, boost::thread doesn't provide a standard solution and there are a couple of tricky things when implementing (possible deadlocks, behaviour when queue is full, use polymorphic messages...)

Answer (score 0):

You should use `mutex` and/ro `semaphore` to synchronize your threads and lock variable to achieve thread-safe communication. Just note that all `threads` in your process share the same memory so you can access the same data, but you have to do it in a thread-safe way.

I'm not sure if `boost` library implements any threading primitives, but here is a good tutorial about multi-threading programming using POSIX threads - http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html